# Why my code not working while executing while loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

Code is below

```
def stringtofind(masterstring, startchar, endchar):
    result = []
    current_pos = masterstring.find(startchar) 
    while current_pos != -1:     
        end_pos = masterstring.find(endchar)
        result.append(masterstring[current_pos:end_pos]) 
    return result
stringtofind("ABCDEABA", "C", "A")
```

Code is infinitely looping and not throwing any output

Expected out is `['CDEA', 'CDEABA']`

Is there any alternate way to execute this like `for i in range(len(masterstring))`

Comment: You never modify `current_pos`, so the loop will never end.

Comment: First, there seems to be some problem with this logic, in your third line you found position of position, then in 5th line you found position of endchar, but you didn't actually checked if end_pos is greater than current_pos, you need to make sure that the end_pos is always greater than current_pos, else the string indice on 6th line, won't return substring for it

Comment: I would recommend [pythontutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html) if you want to get a sense of what your code is doing step-by-step (or learn a debugger!)

Comment: This problem can be easily solved by using regex, it's also more efficient!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution in my mind. Time complexity O(n^2).

```
def stringtofind(masterstring, startchar, endchar):
    result = []
    start_ids = []
    n = len(masterstring)
    for i in range(n):
        if masterstring[i] == startchar:
            start_ids.append(i)
        if masterstring[i] == endchar:
            for j in start_ids:
                result.append(masterstring[j:i+1])
    return(result)

print(stringtofind("ABCDEABA", "C", "A"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`current_pos` and `end_pos` are always set to the same values therefore the while condition will always be `True`.

Actually the first values assigned to them are `current_pos=2` and `end_pos=0` which lead to appending the same empty list to `result`.

Here is a log of the output:

```
current_pos=2, end_pos = 0
result=['']
current_pos=2, end_pos = 0
result=['', '']
current_pos=2, end_pos = 0
result=['', '', '']
current_pos=2, end_pos = 0
result=['', '', '', '']
current_pos=2, end_pos = 0
result=['', '', '', '', '']
...
```

See how the values don't change, they will never make the while loop stop. Moreover the result is appending `masterstring[2:0]` each time, which is the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Here, your code based approach:

```
def stringtofind(masterstring, startchar, endchar):
    result = []
    current_pos = masterstring.find(startchar) 
    for i in range(current_pos,len(masterstring)+1):
        if(masterstring[i] != endchar): return
        result.append(masterstring[current_pos:i]) 
    return result
stringtofind("ABCDEABA", "C", "A")
```